# Using jQueryUI 1.12.1 blocks triggering event $(window).on('load', f)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When I used jQuery 1.12.4 together with jQueryUI 1.12.1, merged in one JS file, which is ASYNC loaded into HTML, there is impossible define event `$(window).on('load', f)` in jQuery document-ready function `$(function(){...})`.

Especially, when page-content loads up faster than start jQuery script (i.e. is cached), document-ready event is fired, but `$(window).on('load')` is skipped. Only when page must load some new non-cached content (i.e. large photo), then document-ready event done and then also fired event `$(window).on('load', f)`, which I can see in console.

Another strange behavior is, that when I use only jQuery 1.12.4 framework (without UI), there is no problem with defining `$(window).on('load', f)` in `$(function(){ ... });`.

I've done some test with simple script. I expected that all logs with "Loaded statement" will be showed after documentReady logs, but they are showed in "randomly" order. Only one solution is load Javascript normally (not ASYNC), but Google don't like such methods.

Does anyone can help with this please?

```
var loaded = false;
window.addEventListener('load', function (){
    loaded = true;
});

$(window).on('load', function (){
    console.log('Content loaded by jQuery A');
});

$(function(){

    if ( loaded === true ) {
        console.log('Content loaded by ROOT');
    } else {
        $(window).on('load', function (){
            console.log('Content loaded by jQuery B');
        });
    }   

    console.log('jQuery Ready Event'); 
});

$(window).on('load', function (){
    console.log('Content loaded by jQuery A2');
});

$(function(){

    if ( loaded === true ) {
        console.log('Content loaded by ROOT 2');
    } else {
        $(window).on('load', function (){
            console.log('Content loaded by jQuery B2');
        });
    }

    console.log('jQuery Ready Event 2'); 
});
```

This is order of event in my console:

```
Content loaded by jQuery A
Content loaded by jQuery A2
Content loaded by ROOT
jQuery Ready Event
Content loaded by ROOT 2
jQuery Ready Event 2
```

After remove jQueryUI or switch ASYNC to SYNC loading javascript:

```
jQuery Ready Event
jQuery Ready Event 2
Content loaded by jQuery A
Content loaded by jQuery A2
Content loaded by jQuery B
Content loaded by jQuery B2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `load` event on the `window` object only fires once. If you attempt to listen for this event after it has already fired, you'll never receive it.

The only reliable way to listen for this event is to do it in a directly-loaded, non-async, non-defer `script` tag. Anything else runs the risk of missing the event because you are too late.

As far as *why* jQuery UI is affecting this behavior, it could be any number of things. But the bottom line is that it will never be reliable to listen for a `load` event inside any other kind of asynchronous event.

Here is a simple example, where I try to listen for the `load` event *inside* a `load` listener, both with `addEventListener` and with jQuery. For clarity, I'm putting the JavaScript code inside an explicit `<script>` tag instead of the usual JavaScript section of a code snippet:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    window.addEventListener( 'load', function() {
        console.log( 'load event with addEventListener' );
        window.addEventListener( 'load', function() {
        console.log( 'load event with NESTED addEventListener' );
        });
    });

    $(window).on( 'load', function() {
        console.log( 'load event with jQuery' );
        $(window).on( 'load', function() {
            console.log( 'load event with NESTED jQuery' );
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see when you run this, only the outer `load` events are received. The nested listeners (set up inside the original `load` event) are never called.

You definitely should not listen for `window.load` inside a jQuery `ready` function like your `$(function...)`. This runs the same risk of the `load` event already having been fired. The `ready` event *may* be fired before `load`, but there is no guarantee of this.

Note that the jQuery `ready` function is very different from a normal browser event. It's a pseudo-event that jQuery itself manages. If you call it multiple times before it's been fired, jQuery makes a list of all the callbacks, and calls them all when it decides it's ready. And you use a `ready` function even *after* it's already been fired: in that case jQuery calls your callback immediately (or possibly after a zero-millisecond delay, I would have to check the code to be sure).

What is it you are actually trying to do? Maybe we can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for fast respond. Everything is clear for me, except one thing - I didn't know that I shouldn't define jQuery on('load') listener in jQuery document-ready function $(function(){ ... }).

I have more complex project, where I merging multiple scripts into 1 file (processed with task runner Grunt, clear javascript and script based on jQuery & jQuery UI), which is loaded into HTML by , so script run after loading and it don't have to wait for loading scripts from other files. I wrote some classes, based on jQuery, with this structure:

```
var InDropdown = function (options) {

    var vars = {};

    var root = this;

    this.construct = function(options){

        vars = $.extend({            
            param: 'value',
        }, options);

        $(window).on('load.dropdown', function(){
            // run methods for checking CSS properties (f.e. display block/none), which can I read only if whole content is loaded
        });

        $(window).on('resize.dropdown', function(){
            // run methods for customize behaviour by actual window size
        });

    };

};

// initialization when jQuery Document Ready into global variable
var inDropdown = {};

$(function(){
    inDropdown = new InDropdown();
});
```

It works while only jQuery framework is merged into JS file. But when I add jQueryUI, then on('load') in constructor never start (neither before document-ready event).

Do you think that is some another solution for firing methods on "jQuery document-ready" && "jQuery on.('load')" event together?